# Mimic std::map<string, std::list<string> > in VBA

Tags: c++, arrays, vba, dictionary

I am trying to mimic `std::map<string, std::list<string> >` in VBA (this case is very specific, but really any collection inside a n`std::map<>`-like container)

I have found that the equivalent of `std::map` would be a `Dictionary`, but how about the last part?

Somehow the most I've found on the internet is that it is possible to add an array element like this to a `Dictionary`, though without any insight as to how to add elements AFTER this has been done:

```
Dim my_dictionary as Dictionary
Set my_dictionary = New Dictionary
my_dictionary.Add "KEY#1", Array("A", "B", "C")
'How would I add "D" here ?!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim arr, ub

    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

    d.Add "key1", Array("A", "B", "C")

    Debug.Print Join(d("key1"))

    arr = d("key1")
    ub = UBound(arr) + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To ub)
    arr(ub) = "D"
    d("key1") = arr

    Debug.Print Join(d("key1"))

End Sub
```